# Particle in a Circle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

A particle is free to move on a smooth vertical circle of radius $r$. It is projected from its lowest point with a velocity just sufficient to carry it to the highest point. Find the velocity.

I didn't understand why the answer is $\sqrt{4gr}$. If the velocity is ${4gr}$, the reaction force becomes 0 at a point and then the particle would leave the circular path and describe a parabolic path whose vertex(point of maximum height) lies below the highest point. Can someone tell what I am missing?

Comment: Draw the free-body diagram for the particle at the very top of the circle and figure out what the speed need to be so that it *just* stays in/on the circle. Then, you can use conservation of energy to figure out how fast it was going at the bottom.

Comment: @march, I want to know what happens when the reaction force becomes 0. Will the particle leave the circle? As it happens in case of prticle tied with a string in a vertical circle.

Comment: The question implies the particle is on a circular track that it cannot leave, so this is not the same as having a particle on the end of a string. If the particle is on a circular track that it cannot leave the speed at the top can be zero.

Comment: @JohnRennie, but the reaction force become 0 at a point, what happens then? If there is no contact, won't the partcile describe a parabolic path?

Comment: @quertyquerty It's like a bead sliding on a circular wire. The bead cannot leave the wire so it is constrained to move in a circle regardless of its speed.

Answer (score 3):

The speed is because at the bottom the Kinetic Energy is
$$ K = \frac{1}{2} m v^2 \ $$
and at the top of the circle it is equal to  Potential energy,
$$ P = mg(2r)$$ , 'r' being the radius of the circle
$$ \frac{1}{2} m v^2 \ = mg(2r)$$
Therefore, $$v= \sqrt{4gr} $$
The reaction force is in picture till the object is in contact with the body and as the circle on which the particle can  move in a circle it won't leave it(assuming the resistive force to be 0)
The velocity follows conservation of energy. After reaching the top it again converts to kinetic energy at the bottom and so on.

Edit: Now I got what you are asking, from your string example. See a particle moving in a circle will exert a force outward so as soon as the reaction force is removed there won't be anything to balance the outward force or its momentum. So it would go in the direction of tangent to the circle at the point the force is removed.

Comment: Yes it goes in direction of tangent, but what what would the trajectory? Won't it be a parabola(since there is no contact between particle and the circle)?

Comment: under gravity it would become parabolic otherwise its just the same

Comment: see this for illustration: https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/centripetal-force-and-gravitation/centripetal-forces/v/bowling-ball-in-vertical-loop